# COUNTIFS VLOOKUP returns a value?

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I'm stuck for a formula. Essentially what i want to do is count the number of times a particular value appears in one sheet, based on data pulled from another sheet.

E.g. I have three sheets. One sheet has a list of jobs and a code associated with a client. The second sheet has a list of the clients and details on the client. The third sheet is my results sheet.

I want to count the How Heards for each company. Eg, in sheet 1 below Apple has 3 customers. If we use the Client Code Id's and go to Sheet 2, we can see that it will total 2 Online and 0 Facebook. This result displays on Sheet 3. The results sheet.

**Sheet 1 Example**

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet 2 Example**

[image: Sheet 2]

**Sheet 3 Example (What i want the results to look like from calculation)**

[image]

Comment: I gather that in a real-world situation that the numerical values in Sheet1!A:A and Sheet2!A:A do not match row-by-row.

Comment: No they don't. There are tens of thousands of rows and some of the client codes in sheet 2, wont exist in sheet 1 :(

Comment: Is there a reason that a 'helper' column could not be added to Sheet1 that reproduced the results in Sheet2? Essentially, the way it sits you want to turn Excel into a relational database with two tables producing a SELECT COUNT JOIN GROUP BY result using native worksheet formulas. At best this would be an extremely inefficient worksheet formula (for 'tens of thousands of rows').

Comment: I considered using a helper column. E.g. using a VLOOKUP to get the business name from Sheet 1 based on client code, and adding it to a new column in sheet 2. Then simply counting the values that contain the business name and the how heard value i'm after.

The only problem with this was that this report will be ran monthly, each month the number of rows will change, so i can either populate the entire column with the VLOOKUP formula (but this increases the file size to much), or drag it down every month, which is semi inconvenient :/

Comment: However, as i'd have no idea where to start regarding a relational database, i think i might have to go with the helper column ha.

Comment: If you are concerned that the number of rows change, remember that you would have to either use dynamically defined named ranges in the third worksheet's formula(s) or full column references in a formula that does not self-truncate at the limits of the used rane(s). If you are worried about the extents of the 'helper' column's VLOOKUP, just add its maintenance to the task of adding the monthly data.

Comment: Another option might be [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6E92E2F4-2079-4E1F-BAD5-89F6269CD605) but you have not indicated the version of Excel you are using.

Comment: Im using Excel 2013. I haven't heard of those before, but will research now. Thanks for the link provided :) Also, thank you for all your help. I'll most likely go with the simple helper column. Have a good morning/day/evening.

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of actually providing a suitable answer to this question, here is some VBA code that allows a workbook to create an ADO connection to itself and generate a report using SELECT, DISTINCT, WHERE, INNER JOIN, GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses.

```
Sub Inner_Join()
    Dim cnx As Object, rs As Object
    Dim sWS1 As String, sWS2 As String, sWB As String, sCNX As String, sSQL As String
    Dim ws1TBLaddr As String, ws2TBLaddr As String

    'Collect some string literals that will be used to build SQL
    ws1TBLaddr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)
    sWS1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Name
    ws2TBLaddr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address(0, 0)
    sWS2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Name
    sWB = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    'Build the connection string
    'The first is for 64-bit Office; the second is more universal
    sCNX = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sWB _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    sCNX = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sWB _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    'Debug.Print sCNX

    'Create the necessary ADO objects
    Set cnx = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  'late binding; for early binding add
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")    'Microsoft AxtiveX Data Objects 6.1 library

    'Open the connection to itself
    cnx.Open sCNX

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        'Clear the reporting area
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents

        'get [Business Name] list from Sheet1
        sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT w1.[Business Name]"
        sSQL = sSQL & " FROM [" & sWS1 & "$" & ws1TBLaddr & "] w1"
        sSQL = sSQL & " ORDER BY w1.[Business Name]"
        'Debug.Print sSQL

        'Populate Sheet3!A:A
        rs.Open sSQL, cnx
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            'Debug.Print rs.Fields("Business Name")
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = rs.Fields("Business Name")
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs.Close

        'get [How Heard] list from Sheet2
        sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT w2.[How Heard]"
        sSQL = sSQL & " FROM [" & sWS2 & "$" & ws2TBLaddr & "] w2"
        sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE w2.[How Heard] NOT LIKE 'None'"
        sSQL = sSQL & " ORDER BY w2.[How Heard]"
        'Debug.Print sSQL

        'Populate Sheet3!1:1
        rs.Open sSQL, cnx
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            'Debug.Print rs.Fields("How Heard")
            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = rs.Fields("How Heard")
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs.Close

        'start by seeding zeroes for all
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)
                .Cells = 0
            End With
        End With

        'get the counts for the [Business Name]×[How Heard] combinations
        sSQL = "SELECT  COUNT(w1.[Business Name]), w1.[Business Name], w2.[How Heard]"
        sSQL = sSQL & " FROM [" & sWS1 & "$" & ws1TBLaddr & "] w1"
        sSQL = sSQL & " INNER JOIN [" & sWS2 & "$" & ws2TBLaddr & "] w2 ON w1.[Client Code] = w2.[Client Code]"
        sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE w2.[How Heard] <> 'None'"
        sSQL = sSQL & " GROUP BY w1.[Business Name], w2.[How Heard]"
        'Debug.Print sSQL

        'Populate Sheet3 data matrix area
        rs.Open sSQL, cnx
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            Do While Not rs.EOF
                'Debug.Print rs.Fields(0) & ":" & rs.Fields(1) & ":" & rs.Fields(2)
                .Cells(Application.Match(rs.Fields(1), .Columns(1), 0), _
                       Application.Match(rs.Fields(2), .Rows(1), 0)) = rs.Fields(0)
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
        rs.Close
    End With

Final_Cleanup:
    Set rs = Nothing
    cnx.Close: Set cnx = Nothing

End Sub
```

Results should be similar to the following.

[image: ADO_Inner_Join_XL]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I am really impressed with the answer by @Jeeped
My answer is not as flexible as being able to use arbitrary SQL but it doesn't use VBA so it might be useful as well in some contexts.

So my answer basically:

- creates an array from Sheet1 that contains the client code for each matching cell
  (or 0 for non matching cells)

  ```
  X = ((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000=$A2)*Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000)
  ```
- creates an array from Sheet2 that contains the client code for each matching cell
  (or 0 for non matching cells)

  ```
  Y = ((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$2000=B$1)*Sheet2!$A$2:$A$2000)
  ```
- compares every cell in the two arrays where the value of the first array isn't 0

  ```
  Z = (X<>0)*(X=TRANSPOSE(Y))
  ```
- and then sums up the number of matches:

  ```
  =SUM(Z)
  ```

So the final formula for Sheet3!B2 is:

```
=SUM((((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000=$A2)*Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000)<>0)*(((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000=$A2)*Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1000)=TRANSPOSE(((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$2000=B$1)*Sheet2!$A$2:$A$2000))))
```

It is an array formula so you need to press Control-Shift-Enter instead of just Enter.  Then you need to copy it from B2 to C2, B3 and so on.

Obviously, You will have to change the 1000 to something bigger than the largest rwo on Sheet1 and the 2000 to something bigger than the largest row on Sheet2.

Comment: Given that the cell ranges in array formulas should ideally be only **exactly** as large as they need to be, the ranges could be defined as `Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH(1e99, Sheet1!$A:$A))` and `Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH(1e99, Sheet1!$A:$A))`. The cell references for Sheet2 could follow suit. This would also eliminate the need to adjust the formulas for a new month's data.

Comment: I really like both of these answers. The amount of work put into it! Thank you guys. My favourite (only through ease of use) is this one with the addition of Jeeped's comment using the INDEX function. However, just to throw a spanner in the works. How easy is it to surround this with conditions? If, for exmaple, it needs to split the numbers into weeks. I have 2 date fields (1 starting date, and 1 ending date) that i use in other formulas to condition it so that it grabs only the data higher/equal to the first date and lower/equal to the second date.

Comment: Alternatively i can change my reports so they're queried by date which would probably be much easier, then i just use the modified forumla above ha. Just a thought is all as i want to see how easy/hard it would be to include.

Comment: @Noodelz more conditions can be multiplied just like the ones that search for the Business Name and How Heard conditions.  I may try to update the answer.